# Error in using PyQt4 with python 3.5.2 for running a PyMoskito example

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to get an example of [PyMoskito](https://github.com/cklb/pymoskito) running under Python 3.5.2 Win7 64 bit
This library needs PyQt4 which in turn needs SIP.

**1-** I installed SIP using `pip3 install SIP` which ended up successfully (with a notice to update my pip).

**2-** I even barely know Python. So I tried installing PyQt4 with a binary executable. The binaries provided at [riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) are for python 3.4 so I downloaded an unofficial wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4 with a name `PyQt4-4.11.4-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl`. Then I `cd`'ed into the respective directory and installed it with `pip` which ended up successfully.

Now, I don't know what is the standard procedure for testing if a library is working. So I ran `setup.py` from the main directory of library and I assumed it set things up. Then I ran an example from `examples` folder and I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\Documents\Python Libraries\pymoskito-master\pymoskito-master\examples\ballbeam\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I assume python could NOT find the PyQt4 dependencies. I searched stackoverflow and non of the solutions worked. Here is what I tried so far:

- There is NO /bin directory in `C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4`. So all dlls are already in the \PyQt4 directory
- I added this directory to System `PATH` env. var. Same error occurs
- I appended this directory to `sys.path` and tested it. Same error occurs
- I created a \bin directory and copied all \PyQt4 into it. Then added it to PATH. Same error occurs
- After that, I installed python 2.7 and PyQt4 from riverbankcomputing but not SIP. I still have the same problem

I really don't know what else should I do. I'm actually frustrated by all the mentioning of whether OP is using Python 2 or Python 3 or QT4 or QT5 or x86 or x64. I believe backward compatibility should be the minimum of a programming language and this is definitely a mess for Python

Comment: 1) Python 3 is not backwards compatible with Python 2 code. 2) Knowing whether you are using 32 or 64 bit matters, since a 32-bit library may not work with a 64-bit Python installation. 3) Qt is also not necessarily backwards-compatible, and this has nothing to do with Python. 4) Many *scripting* languages introduce breaking changes in *major releases* of their code, e.g. upgrading from v2 to v3. 5) If you want people to help you, answering their questions and not disparaging them for trying to help is a good start. kthxbai

Comment: @Dan Where did I **disparage** someone? I just expressed my view towards python 3 vs 2 . If I offended anyone, I'm sorry

Comment: "I'm actually frustrated by all the mentioning of whether OP is using Python 2 or Python 3 or QT4 or QT5 or x86 or x64. I believe backward compatibility should be the minimum of a programming language and this is definitely a mess for Python". "mentioning" in reference to the "OP" is a *human* behavior. Just pointing that out, I didn't DV or anything.

Comment: What does MVC++ has to do with this problem? And are you sure about Python 3 thing?

Comment: There is no doubt that compiling qt (and VTK!) and getting things to link with it is tricky, especially on windows. You may want to try the Anaconda distribution, which includes binary compiled versions of qt4, dependency management and multiple environments safely side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, I believe is that you have pyqt4 (a python interface to the qt4 library), sip (an automated c++-to-python communication library) but not qt4 itself (the UI library). qt4 is it's own monolithic c++ project with its own build and dependency problems.

You may be able to find the various pieces at  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke , but I would recommend installing the Anaconda distribution of python ( https://www.continuum.io/downloads ), which provides binary packages for things like qt4 and pyqtgraph, the former of which is installed by default, the latter requiring a command like

```
conda install pyqtgraph
```

After this, pip install of pymoskito should work.

There is also mention in the readme of vtk, but it is not in the requirememnts. vtk is also a monolithic c++ library and hard to build, but conda has that too, albeit not in the default channel for py35:

```
conda install vtk -c menpo
```

Comment: Thank you, But I prefer to stick to official Python

Comment: Your choice, of course, how to install things, but there is no "official" python, and you are already relying on `gohlke` to do your compiling for you. If you want to compile everything from source from scratch, I can only wish you good luck.